# Can't run GIMP, 64-bit error

Tags: 64-bit, gimp, libraries

After upgrading to 12.04, I wasn't able to run GIMP. Now I installed the latest 2.8 from PPA, and still am unable to run it. I get the error:

```
gimp: error while loading shared libraries: libgegl-0.0.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

strangely enough, gimp ***is*** 64-bit:

```
$ file /usr/bin/gimp-2.8
/usr/bin/gimp-2.8: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs)....
```

So why can't I run it? I reinstalled libgegl, I have 0.0.22 and 0.2.0 versions installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started to get it working by uninstalling, then removing leftover files (I had compiled gimp at some point earlier), which are reported with `whereis gimp`. Now after reinstall, it started up with error, second startup complained about files in /usr/share/gimp nonexistent. After apt-get purge and install of gimp-data and gimp packages, it works!